# C#/XNA - RenderTarget2D.GetData(), RenderTarget2D.SetData(): is it efficient for cloning textures per frame?

Tags: c#, xna, textures, texture2d, rendertarget

So, since the last question, I found that my solution is to duplicate the texture to prevent reference issues. However, I'm questioning:

```
    Color[] color = new Color[screen.Width * screen.Height];
    InputRenderTarget2D.GetData(Color);
    OutputRenderTarget2D.SetData(color);
```

For one, is this efficient when ran 60 times per second? Although it's setting 1 texture, I'm performance-paranoid and WANT to keep performance at its decent or best. Will it cause "majorly-noticable framedrops" and the like?

Second, will it boost performance that instead of creating a new Color array, I recycle one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this will harm performance because the GetData()/SetData() calls will transfer the rendertarget data to main memory. IMO, the better alternative would be to render InputRenderTarget2D to OutputRenderTarget2D using a quad of the same size. This will prevent CPU-GPU data transfer.

Comment: So, set the render target to OutputRenderTarget, then render InputRenderTarget onto that via GPU rendering w/ quad or spritebatch?

Comment: ... is using spritebatch a possible way too

Comment: Correct. And sure, you can render the quad any way you wish.

Comment: Except, when I try to render OutputRenderTarget to Input via:

Comment: `setRenderTarget(input) spritebatch.draw(output) setRenderTarget(null)`

it says I can't use the render target when it's set on the card. That's what I'm stuck at.

Comment: Which is why I asked this question, since I have a texture being set to a REFERENCE of the outputrendertarget, and need a clone of it.

Comment: Strange, that should work. Could you post the exact exception and some sample code?

Comment: I was initializing the rendertargets via
`input = output = new RenderTarget2D(...)` which was causing the reference errors.